# MySQL Query To find Trains between stations

Tags: mysql

My Train Time Table Structure,

```
Table Name- timming_tb
Train_Number  Station  Time
16636          ABC     09:00am  
16636          CDE     10:00am
16636          FGH     11:00am
16637          FGH     12:00pm
16637          CDE     01:00pm
16637          ABC     02:00pm
```

User will give from and to as input
the output will be all train number

ie,For input From- CDE  To-FGH  ----> output will be 16636

and For input From- FGH  To-CDE  ----> output will be 16637

i tried the following query

```
SELECT Train_Number FROM 'timming_tb' WHERE Station="CDE" or Station="FGH"
```

but it shows all train number having code CDE and FGH

Comment: Your sample query shows you haven't the foggiest clue about the underlying problem you're trying to solve. I'd recommend a handful of SQL books before trying to tackle this (actually far from trivial) problem.

Comment: SELECT x FROM my_table WHERE station IN ('a','b') GROUP BY x HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;

Comment: @Niels I disagree that this is far from trivial.. and although the initial attempt is not very close, the question is still valid.

Comment: @Strawberry That returns both trains for both queries and does not consider the order of the stations.

Comment: @Arth Good point. A small (if slightly clumsy) modification would work - but under the circumstances, I'd actually take a slightly different approach.

Comment: @Arth for someone who writes that query as a solution to this problem anything involving self-joins and/or subqueries is in my opinion 'far from trivial'.

Comment: @Neils Point taken.. Indeed. I was taking 'far from trivial' in the broader sense.

Comment: @user3159707 What is the data type of the Time column - varchar? time?

Answer (score 1):

You should really change your time column to a standard 24Hr time for this calculation;
then it is not too complicated:

```
SELECT train_number
  FROM timming_tb tt1
 WHERE tt1.station = 'CDE'
   AND EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
           FROM timming_tb tt2
          WHERE tt2.train_number = tt1.train_number
            AND tt2.station = 'FGH'
            AND tt2.time > tt1.time
       )
```

N.B This will return all viable trains in the case of a more complete table, but you can apply some filtering/ordering logic if you need.

Answer (score 1):

The following query performs a self-join.

```
SELECT 
  tt1.train_number
FROM timming_tb tt1
INNER JOIN timming_tb tt2
ON tt1.train_number = tt2.train_number AND concat(right(tt2.time, 2), replace(tt2.time, '12:', '00:')) > concat(right(tt1.time, 2), replace(tt1.time, '12:', '00:'))
WHERE tt1.station = 'CDE'
AND tt2.station = 'FGH';
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bf254b/10)</kbd>

**References**:

Answer (score 0):

Using a self join you can do this:-

```
SELECT a.Train_Number
FROM train_time a
INNER JOIN train_time b
ON a.Train_Number = b.Train_Number
AND b.Time > a.Time
WHERE a.Station = 'CDE'
AND b.Station = 'FGH'
```

assuming that you have a real time field for the time

If you wanted only the trains that went directly from CDE to FGH with no intermediate stations you could add a LEFT OUTER JOIN to the table looking for stations with a time between the other 2:-

```
SELECT a.Train_Number
FROM train_time a
INNER JOIN train_time b
ON a.Train_Number = b.Train_Number
AND b.Time > a.Time
LEFT OUTER JOIN train_time c
ON a.Train_Number = c.Train_Number
AND c.Time > a.Time 
AND c.Time < b.Time
WHERE a.Station = 'CDE'
AND b.Station = 'FGH'
AND c.Station IS NULL
```